# Is there a better way to format multiple events?

Tags: jquery

Ok so I have multiple things happening here on one click but I'm wondering if there is a better way to format or do it?

```
<ul><li>Hello</li><li>Welcome</li><li>Howdy</li></ul>
<div class="first">Goodbye</div><div class="second">See ya</div><div class="third">Later Gator</div>

$('li:first-child').click(function(){
$('li:nth-child(2)').removeClass('this');
$('li:nth-child(3)').removeClass('this');
$('.second').hide();
$('.third').hide();
$('li:first-child').addClass('this');
$('.first').show(); });
```

Respectively, doing it this way I need the same process when the other's are clicked.

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/thatrockz/5EYBf/16/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this?

```
$('li:first-child').click(function(){
    $(this).addClass('this').next().removeClass('this').next().removeClass('this');
    $('.second, .third').hide();
    $('.first').show(); 
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `this` keyword which refers to the clicked element. Surely you have other div or li elements in your page, you can add classes to your elements that distinguishes these elements from other elements.

```
$('li').click(function(){
    var $this = $(this), ind = $this.index();
    $this.addClass('this').siblings().removeClass('this');
    $('div').hide().eq(ind).show()
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('ul').on('li','click', function(ev) {
    // your code
});
```

As this approach avoids multiple event bindings. jQuery just looks for a single click event on the UL element that bubbles up the dom but please correct me if I'm wrong.